# IE get URL parameters failing

Tags: javascript, url, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have a function that is supposed to be getting the URL parameters but is breaking in IE (using 11) only. I initially thought it was because of some of the newer ES6 features and syntax so wrote it up for ES5. however it still isn't working. Does anybody know what can be done or fixed to make this work on a really old legacy project. I did try the polyfill from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill) for Object.Assign.

ES6:

```
getQueryURLParams = function(pName) {
   var urlObject = location.search
   .slice(1)
   .split('&')
   .map(function(element ) { 
    return element.split('='); 
})
.reduce(function(obj, pair) {  

  const key = pair.map(decodeURIComponent)[0];
  const value = pair.map(decodeURIComponent)[1];

  return Object.assign({}, obj, { [key]: value });
}, {});

return urlObject[pName];
};
```

ES5 version:

```
getQueryURLParams = function(pName) {

var urlObject = location.search
.slice(1)
.split('&')
.map(function(element ) { 
    return element.split('='); 
})
.reduce(function(obj, pair) {  

  const key = pair.map(decodeURIComponent)[0];
  const value = pair.map(decodeURIComponent)[1];

  return Object.assign({}, obj, { [key]: value });
}, {});

return urlObject[pName];
};
```

I appreciate any advice

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign doesn't work in IE since it is not part of ES5.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

On the bottom of the page, there is a polyfill

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill

`[key]: value`

this isn't valid ES5 either.

you could just write

```
var result = {}
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k){
    result[k] = obj[k];
})
result[key] = value;

return result;
```